# Mysysgit "(END)" displays, how do I proceed?

Tags: windows, git, logging, git-bash

While using mysysgit under Windows, I do not know how to regain control of the console windows after running **git log** in Git Bash. This seems simple yet I cannot find the key combination or command, so I find myself having to close the console window and relaunching a new instance of Git Bash to interact with git.

What is the key combination and/or command I need to exit the log viewer?

Comment: Press the letter "q".

Comment: In case you're curious, you're looking at the default pager, called "less". Type `man less` in Git Bash or check out http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?less for more key bindings.

Comment: @peterjmag – thanks! I wouldn't have even thought to consider that it's using the "default pager", tho that makes a lot of sense considering the platform on which Git was first developed.

Comment: "q" worked for me, specifically after paging through lengthy man pages ("man ls" for example). wacky bash shell.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

As said in the comments already, press the Q key.

Comment: Works fine for me in Windows 7.

Comment: doesn't work for me either,just goes blank and then I can't type anything,I am on windows 7  too

Answer (score 4):

In `WINDOWS 10` git Bash :

type `q` here q is `QUIT`

**Alternate Answer** : `clrt + z` and then press `q`

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer worked for me: type 'q'

An **alternate answer**:   **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  -  <kbd>z</kbd>**

Comment: Ctrl-Z doesn't work. It makes a sound for "wrong key shortcut".

Answer (score 1):

If q does not work just type quit and enter. This worked for me.

-edit
This was in power shell though.